# Ajax calls in JQuery always return successfully but 'data' parameter is an empty string

Tags: php, jquery

I am just trying to test a simple ajax call on my server using jquery

I have a HTML file like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
            $("#connect_button").click(function(event){
                $("#placeholder").load("http://mysever/AjaxResponse.php");
            })
       });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="connect_button" type="button">Connect</button>
    <span id="placeholder">This has not worked</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

AjaxResponse.php, which works when accessed from the browser statically, looks like this

```
<?php
    echo "This now works";
?>
```

The code runs and the replace happens the only problem is that the page returns a blank string causing the span to be empty

If I change the code to use another jQuery call such as $.get() the callback is sent back the textStatus of "Success" and a data value of ""

What am I missing here? Do severs need to be set up to respond to Ajax calls. Am I misusing jquery?

Comment: what is the URL you are using for your above HTML file in browser ?

Comment: **http://mysever/AjaxResponse.php** does not seems to be right path for your **AjaxResponse.php** file. Use this URL in your browser directly to see if it echo the statement. I placed both HTML file and **AjaxResponse.php** in same folder and it is working for me. If your HTML file and **AjaxResponse.php** will be in same folder then you will do like this: `$("#placeholder").load("AjaxResponse.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your AjaxResponse.php on the same domain? Ajax calls won't work cross-site.

Comment: Thanks. I was running the html file locally. When I put the html on the server and changed the jQuery reference to a relative one it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could check if the loaded page has anything in it like this:

```
$(function(){

$('#connect_button').live('click', function(){

content = $.get('test.php',function(data){
content = data;

if (content != ""){
$('#placeholder').html(content);
}else{
$('#placeholder').html('This has not worked');
}

});
});
})
```

That way if the returned data is empty, it will put "This has not worked" in the placeholder id.

Comment: In this case data comes back as an empty string so it would display 'This has not worked'